# RapidMiner : Can't get JWT Token

Tags: rapidminer

I am refering below document to get JWT Token .
However when I call the API /api/rest/tokenservice it doesn't return the token but returns a web interface asking for login . How can I get JWT Token

REST API Url :
https://docs.rapidminer.com/9.10/hub/rest-api/index.html

[image]

Response of postman:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order to query the internal tokenservice endpoint, you need a valid "session". In the native installation method, you can use basic auth as "session" as outlined in the documentation.

```
curl -u user:pass "http://localhost:8080/api/rest/tokenservice"

{
  "idToken": "the-valid-token",
  "expirationDate": "the-exp"
}
```

However, for this to work when you've deployed RapidMiner AI Hub with Keycloak (and docker), you need to 1. enable basic auth for Keycloak, 2. access the route by first having a valid "login session" (cookie name is RM_SERVER_JSESSIONID) or 3. use a valid Keycloak token.

**Enable basic auth in Keycloak**

```
rm-server-homedir/configuration/keycloak/keycloak.json

{
...
"enable-basic-auth": true,
...
}
```

**Valid cookie value**

Login via web interface, open the browser's developer tools and use the very same RM_SERVER_JSESSIONID cookie value inside the REST request issued to the /api/rest/tokenservice endpoint.
Not sure what you like to achieve, e.g. schedule a process via REST, I like to outline that you can easily add a process and trigger via Web Service. The triggered process could make use of the [Admin Tools extension](https://marketplace.rapidminer.com/UpdateServer/faces/product_details.xhtml?productId=rmx_admin). You still need to enable Keycloak's basic auth though if you like to trigger it from "outside". A guide how to use the extension can be found [here](https://docs.rapidminer.com/latest/studio/connect/aihub/).

**Valid Keycloak token**
Retrieve a valid Keycloak access token (from Keycloak's token endpoint, e.g. via OpenID Connect) and query the
*/api/rest/tokenservice* endpoint with Authorization: Bearer .

**Disclaimer:** This answer is used with permission of the original author from the RapidMiner [community](https://community.rapidminer.com/discussion/59567/cant-get-jwt-toke).